# Why is it necessary to call both the prototype and constructor here

Tags: javascript

What exactly is the 'constructor' in the following? That is, what does the `Object.create` do vs. calling the constructor? Does the constructor actually execute the function name, or what magic happens there?

```js
function greet(name) {
    this.print = function print() {console.log('hey!', name)};
}

// why's it required to create an object of the funcion.prototype and again initialize the constructor?
let y = Object.create(greet.prototype);
y.constructor('Bob');
y.print();

// this part makes sense to me.
let z = new greet('Bob');
z.print();
```

Also, if I were to put the `print()` method outside the function, how would I access the name? For example:

```
function greet(name) {
    this.name = name;
}
greet.prototype.print = () => {console.log('hey!', this.name)};
// 'hey! undefined'
```

Comment: It's not necessary, but when there's no properties in `greet.prototype`, you would get an empty object, calling the constructor assgins the own properties to the newly-created object.

Comment: "*What exactly is the 'constructor' in the following?*" -`y.constructor` is inherited from `greet.prototype.constructor` which is `greet`. Same as `greet.call(c, 'Bob')`.

Comment: *"again initialize the constructor"*: what does that mean? The constructor is defined by the `function` statement. It does not get initialised again. If you meant "invoked" instead of "initialized", then it is not invoked *again*. It is just invoked, as `Object.create` does not invoke a constructor.

Comment: Defining a prototype property works fine, you should just not define it using arrow function, which binds a different `this` than you think.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/are-arrow-functions-and-functions-equivalent-interchangeable